# Integral of function with respect to discrete measure - derivation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E, \mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space and $D\subset E$ be a countable subset. Define the following **discrete measure**
$$
\pi(A) = \frac{1}{c}\sum_{x\in D}\delta_x(A) \qquad\qquad \forall \, A\in\mathcal{E} \qquad\qquad  c > 0.
$$
Let $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. I would like to compute the following expectation with respect to the discrete measure $\pi$
$$
\mathbb{E}_\pi[1_Bf]\qquad\qquad B\in\mathcal{E}.
$$

## Attempt

Assuming anything I need to exchange integral and summation:
$$
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}_\pi[1_Bf]
    &= \int_B f(y) \pi(dy) \\
    &= \int_B f(y) \frac{1}{c}\sum_{x\in D} \delta_x(dy) \\
    &= \frac{1}{c}\sum_{x\in D}\int_B f(y) \delta_x(dy) \\
    &= \frac{1}{c}\sum_{x\in D}\int_E 1_B(y) f(y) \delta_x(dy)
\end{align}
$$
and then I can't seem to go further, I feel like there is something wrong with my notation.

Comment: Uuuh maybe
$$
\mathbb{E}_\pi[1_B f] = \frac{1}{c}\sum_{x\in D} 1_B(x) f(x) = \frac{1}{c}\sum_{x\in D\cap B} f(x)
$$

Comment: Recall that $\int g(y)\,\delta_x(\mathrm{d}y)=g(x)$.

Comment: This feels so wrong but somehow must be the solution